# Using a VBA script to validate if an excel workbook is protected and read what password was applied to it while doing so

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing for an application that validates if users perform tasks successfully in various Microsoft applications.  One of these skills is to protect a file with a password.  Is there some property or method I can use to verify if the current file is protected and to verify what password was used to encrypt it?

Comment: What's the point of a password if there's a property that one can read to find out??

Comment: Fair point.  Well is there at the very least a property or method I can read in order to verify that the workbook is protected and encrypted with a password without needing to know what the password is?

Answer (score 2):

As @findwindow mentioned, we wont be able to see the password of a protected sheet or workbook. To check if a workbook/worksheet is protected using VBA, you can do this.
Code is borrowed from [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/2014/12/17/determine-if-workbook-or-worksheet-is-password-protected-with-excel-vba)

**Worksheet protected check**

```
Sub IsWorksheetProtected()
With ActiveSheet
  If .ProtectContents Or .ProtectDrawingObjects Or .ProtectScenarios Then
    MsgBox "This worksheet is password protected"
  Else
    MsgBox "This Worksheet is not password protected"
  End If
End With

End Sub
```

**Worksbook protected check**

```
Sub IsWorkbookProtected()
With ActiveWorkbook
  If .ProtectWindows Or .ProtectStructure Then
    MsgBox "This workbook is password protected"
  Else
    MsgBox "This workbook is not password protected"
  End If
End With

End Sub
```

**UPDATE FOR WORKBOOK PWD**
You are right, as we have the workbook open, looks like it will not detect the details. You can use `.HasPassword` to check if the workbook is password protected. Note that it is possible to lock the workbook without password, but it is counterintuitive to protect a worksheet without a password. But, as long as a password is set, you can use this.

Just replace

```
If .ProtectWindows Or .ProtectStructure Then
```

with

```
If .HasPassword Then
```

Comment: I tried using the latter, but it appears that I just get the "not password protected" message when I run the macro.  Here are the steps I am performing to protect the document:

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click the Protect Workbook button.
3. Click the Encrypt with Password option.
4. Type stdb0123 in the text box.
5. Click the OK button.
6. Type stdb0123 in the text box.
7. Click the OK button.

Comment: @HB729 - you can use .HasPassword.... updated the response with this information